How to decompose the Hessian matrix of a 3rd degree polynomial into 2 or more vectors/matrices?
I am trying to figure out what can be said about the spectral radius of the Hessian of a 3rd degree  random polynomial defined over a unit hypercube, drawing on known results in random matrix theory. In order to even start with this approach I think it could be helpful to decompose the Hessian (it seems like there are just too many relationships and patterns in the un-decomposed matrix). For a polynomial of the form:

$ \frac{c_1}{6}x_1^3 + \frac{c_2}{2}x_{1}^2x_2 + \frac{c_3}{2}x_{1}x_{2}^2 + c_{ignore}x_1^2 + etc$

,ignoring the constant terms in all elements (these can be added by addition of another matrix so are easy to handle), the matrix has, of course, the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1}x_{1} & c_{2}x_{1} + c_{3}x_{2} & c_{4}x_{1}+ c_{5}x_3 & etc \\
c_{2}x_1 + c_{3}x_2 & c_{n+1}x_2 & c_{n+2}x_2 + c_{n+3}x_3 & etc \\
etc & etc & etc & etc 
\end{bmatrix}$$
I am wondering if there is a way to decompose this matrix into 2 or more matrices so that no matrix contains a mix of coefficients $c_i$ and arguments of the function $x_i$ - and as a result I get, in effect, a product (or a sum etc) of several independent random matrices.

In the case of a decomposition of the Hessian of a multivariate polynomial into a product of matrices, here is an interesting article
